# How to Change Difficulty in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the difficulty?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67346/how-can-i-change-the-difficulty)

I played through as a Monk, unlocked Nightmare, went back and played with friends on Normal mode but now want to get back to Nightmare mode. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How do I unlock higher difficulties in Diablo III?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66699)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When selecting a quest, in the bottom left you select the difficulty.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom left of the quest selection screen you have a dropdown where you can select difficulty.

In order to change the difficulty level, you first need to unlock each difficulty. The only difficulty unlocked by default is the Normal difficulty, and you’ll need to play through Normal and beat all Acts, plus get to level 30 in order to unlock and proceed to Nightmare difficulty. For unlocking hell you need to reach level 50 and beat Nightmare and to unlock Inferno you need to beat Hell and reach level 60.